# Hiding Rows Based on Drop down

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where I need to hide certain rows based on a drop down.
[image]
The code I am using to do this is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            X = Target.Value
            If X = "" Or X = "1" Then Rows("10:10").Hidden = True
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
       Y = Target.Value
       If Y <> "California" Then Rows("16:16").Hidden = True
       If Y <> "Florida" Then Rows("16:16").Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem I am running into is when I select the number of owners the rows hidden due to the state choice unhides. Is there something I am not seeing to prevent this?

EDIT: Updated code to include comments suggested. Now any selection I choose hides row 16 and does not unhide.

Comment: `Rows("6:25").Hidden = False` - this runs no matter what cell is changed.

Comment: Note that you are checking `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then` twice. That can be simplified.

Comment: I have made changes based on your suggestions but now it hides based on any selection.

Comment: With my comment, I didn't mean to remove the `Rows("6:25").Hidden = False`, but to move it inside the appropriate block .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to BigBen I figured out where I was going wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
            X = Target.Value
            If X = "" Or X = "1" Then Rows("11:11").Hidden = True
            If X = "2" Then Rows("11:11").Hidden = False
        End If

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
            Y = Target.Value
            If Y <> "California" Then Rows("16:16").Hidden = True
            If Y <> "Florida" Then Rows("16:16").Hidden = True
            If Y = "California" Then Rows("16:16").Hidden = False
            If Y = "Florida" Then Rows("16:16").Hidden = False
        End If

End Sub
```

This works as I need it to. I was not accounting for unhiding when the correct state was selected.

Comment: Would also move `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` outside the `If...End If` - also, use `.CountLarge` instead of `.Count`.

Comment: Switched. Thank you for the assistance!